# Android connect Sql Server uses jtds happen verify error

Tags: android, eclipse, sql-server-2008, jtds

This is my Log file...

```
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957): Process: com.example.jsonconnet, PID: 4957
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957): java.lang.VerifyError: net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/TdsCore
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:359)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at com.example.jsonconnet.Step.CONN(Step.java:120)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at com.example.jsonconnet.Step.onCreate(Step.java:49)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
07-01 16:34:34.161: E/AndroidRuntime(4957):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and then
this is my code
please help me

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_step);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.orange));
    CONN(mUserName,mPassWord,mDB,mSqlServer);
}
private void CONN(String _user, String _pass, String _DB, String _server){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try{
       String ConnURL =null;
       Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
       ConnURL = 
      "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+ _server+";"+"databaseName"+_DB+"integratedSecurity=true;";
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL,_user,_pass);
    }catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

public void InsertSQL(String RECNO){


    String sql="insert into Popularity(fbID,recNo)values(?,?)";
    PreparedStatement prepared;

    try {
        prepared = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        prepared.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt("830914"));
        prepared.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(RECNO));
        prepared.executeUpdate();
        Log.d("XX","Success!");

    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem  likeit = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "like").setIcon(R.drawable.likeit);;
    likeit.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    likeit.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            InsertSQL(recNo);           
            return true;
            }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use version jtds-1.3.0.jar and everything works perfectly :)